# Data Array Undefined React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native

I am trying to map the data I get back from an API in this format:

```
data={[
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 1, y: 1 },
    { x: 2, y: 2 },
    { x: 3, y: 3 },
    { x: 4, y: 4 },
  ]}
```

I have a get call then I map each of the items to give me an x , y value:

```
getCryptoChartData('histohour', selectedCrypto, 24, 1).then(
          cryptoChartData => {
            //const response = cryptoChartData.Data.map(item => item.close);
            const data = cryptoChartData.Data.map(item => {
              [
                {
                  x: item.time,
                  y: item.close,
                },
              ];
            });
            return this.setState({cryptoChartData: data});
          },
        );
```

However, I notice that the data array is set to undefined:

```
<SlideAreaChart
 data={this.state.cryptoChartData}
/>

Am I setting the data array correctly with the mapping?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems the problem is in mapping. You just forget to return the generated object:

```
    const data = cryptoChartData.Data.map(item => {
      return {
          x: item.time,
          y: item.close,
      };
    });
```

or

```
const data = cryptoChartData.Data.map(item => ({
    x: item.time,
    y: item.close,
}));
```

Final code of `getCryptoChartData` method will look like:

```
getCryptoChartData('histohour', selectedCrypto, 24, 1)
    .then(cryptoChartData => {
        const data = cryptoChartData.Data.map(item => ({
            x: item.time,
            y: item.close,
        }));
        this.setState({ cryptoChartData: data });
    });
```

Comment: But I am doing this return this.setState({cryptoChartData: data});

Comment: You don't need that `return`. You need to use the `return` inside the mapping.

Comment: how will it get the cryptoChartData state get updated ? if its not set?

Comment: I meant only the `return`.

You still need to call the `this.setState({cryptoChartData: data});`

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly, why was the way I was doing it wrong?